# How to inform a designer to use a grid for responsive CSS?

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-web, grid, fluid-layout

How do you share information on a grid with a designer / design process, such that it helps in further coding of CSS of a responsive interface?

Do you use any tools in a mock? Do you show blueprints of columns? Do you provide certain settings in a PSD?

EDIT: Maybe a bit more concrete example of the design of a responsive header can help:

Assuming we want to design a responsive header for a web page. With Photoshop, a designer would chose fonts, add spacings, borders, etc. Now, when the design goes to a frontend designer, how does a frontend developer know about choosing grid settings? Or, how could a frontend designer communicate her choice for a grid to a designer? E.g what would be the use for a designer of a grid styleguide, e.g. like the Boostrap grid:  http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: I am not sure i understand this question. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: thanks, I edited the question a bit. Basically, I am confused about defining grid settings. When do they enter the design process, or is it purely needed for getting CSS details right?

Comment: This sounds like a query for graphic designers, not UX folk.

Comment: Ok, sorry, a grid is not something from the UX domain?  Hmm. maybe this question is asked then in the wrong context. Close or delete it? Or any chance to take something out that could be discussed here?

Comment: Ideally the people designing your interfaces understand how responsive design works. And yes, this isn't really UX related. Much more graphic design/front end dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: communication. Don't just send files off and expect the other party to know what to do. You need to talk to each other, as with any other process where documents exchange hands.

To really solve any problems, the designer should know in advance that this design is expected to be translated to a responsive design, and as such should take some grid into account. What kind of grid system is being used by the implementing party (eg. a frontend designer) will probably help them make such decisions. So, sit down together before either of you get started and run through the grid system, what elements of a responsive design the designer must take into account, and move from there.